# How do you stick to an ABI/API in a commercial library?

Tags: api, libraries, abi

How does a commercial library vendor manage to stick to the same ABI over years of development (or is this a bad assumption on my part)?

I would have thought that over time a lot of functions and class interfaces would be completely rewritten. Do they just have the foresight to know what footprint to use from the get-go?

Is it a bad idea to not change the ABI? Like you end up with a horrid ugly mess if you don't; which is more important, ABI staying the same, or the API making sense for a newbie?

EDIT: I may be getting ABI and API confused. As I understand it, changing the API would change the ABI?

Comment: I might be dense but what is an "ABI?"

Comment: @WyattBarnett **Application Binary Interface** API is what programmers use, ABI is how the library is linked to the executable.

Comment: Changing either *might* be a (possibly silent) breaking change in the other, but need not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ABI and API are different, but related things. An API is a contract that describes functionality. The ABI describes how modules communicate *at the machine code level.* The two can change independently, and one doesn't (or shouldn't) affect the other.

The ABI describes things like how parameters are passed to functions (on the stack, in registers, etc.), how system calls are made, how shared data is accessed, etc. An ABI is machine specific, operating system specific, often language specific, and also application specific.

An API, on the other hand, is often machine, operating system, and language agnostic.

There are large parts of the ABI that you don't often have to think about, because your language compiler and linker handle them for you. You might have to worry about it in some cases, for example the difference between `cdecl` and `stdcall` in C and C++. Staying with the same ABI for years is pretty easy for these parts. For example, code written for Win32 in 1995 will still work today. Even libraries that were compiled 20 years ago can be linked with 32-bit code that was compiled today.

Whatever API you're using *should be* steady across versions. Vendors make a concerted effort to keep the APIs backward compatible so that code written to use version 1 of the library can still link with version 5. Or 17. Granted, the API might be extended, but functions that were available in the first version usually exist and work the same many versions later. The internal implementation might be (very often is) different, but as long as the functions meet the initial contract, it doesn't matter how they're implemented.

Now, where you can get into trouble is if you change a data structure that's passed to or returned by an API function. As was pointed out in the comments, a change to a data structure that doesn't require a source code change, is considered an ABI change. That could be something as simple as changing structure packing, or rearranging the order of the individual structure members. Not to mention adding a field. In any of those cases, the size of the data structure could change, but the new version might very well link with an object module that was compiled for the older version. That would definitely break things.

Those are *breaking changes* that, although they don't require any source code changes, *do* require a recompile. And in my opinion if it requires a recompile, then it should be considered an API change.

Comment: I was just reading this https://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++ which indicates that it's very easy to inadvertently make ABI changes.

Comment: You're describing platform-wide aspects of the ABI here, but there are also application-specific aspects.  For example, if you add fields to a data structure, applications that were compiled against the old definition still have the old size compiled in, so they'll allocate less memory for instances than the new version of the library expects.  The size of the structure is part of the library's ABI, so when it changes, you have to recompile the application using the new header file.  (But you haven't broken API, since no source-code changes are needed in the application.)

Comment: @Wyzard: Interesting. I've always considered changing a structure to be an API change. I see that my understanding of ABI / API is somewhat different than what is apparently generally accepted. I will modify my answer accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @NeomerArcana: Thank you for the link. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Adding a field to a structure is an API *change*, but not one that breaks compatibility with existing source code.  But changing the size of a structure is an ABI change that breaks compatibility with existing compiled code.  The two are basically independent; you can also make changes that break API but not ABI (such as *renaming* a field in a structure).  In that case, existing compiled code will continue to work, but you have to change the source code before you can compile it again.

Comment: What does "API  is language agnostic" mean? An API is specified in a language,  so isn't it language specific?

Comment: @Tim From a theoretical standpoint, an API is a description of functionality. The *implementation* of the API might be in a specific language and accessible from any language, but the API itself is language-agnostic. From a more practical standpoint, web APIs are available that are accessible from any language that can make a REST call. Those are definitely language agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

The API is easy to stick to, but the ABI is difficult. For example, ICU has an API for both C and C++:

```
Module Name 			C 		C++  

Basic Types and Constants 	utypes.h 	utypes.h  

Strings and Character Iteration 	ustring.h, utf8.h, utf16.h, UText, UCharIterator 	icu::UnicodeString, icu::CharacterIterator, icu::Appendable, icu::StringPiece,icu::ByteSink  

Unicode Character

Properties and Names 	uchar.h, uscript.h 	C API  

Sets of Unicode Code Points and Strings 	uset.h 	icu::UnicodeSet  

Maps from Strings to Integer Values 	(no C API) 	icu::BytesTrie, icu::UCharsTrie  

Codepage Conversion 	ucnv.h, ucnvsel.hb 	C API  

Codepage Detection 	ucsdet.h 	C API  

Unicode Text Compression 	ucnv.h

(encoding name "SCSU" or "BOCU-1") 	C API  

Locales  	uloc.h 	icu::Locale  

Resource Bundles 	ures.h 	icu::ResourceBundle  

Normalization 	unorm2.h 	icu::Normalizer2  

Calendars 	ucal.h 	icu::Calendar  

Date and Time Formatting 	udat.h 	icu::DateFormat  

Message Formatting 	umsg.h 	icu::MessageFormat  

Number Formatting 	unumberformatter.h, unum.h 	icu::number::NumberFormatter (ICU 60+) or icu::NumberFormat (older versions)  

Number Spellout

(Rule Based Number Formatting) 	unum.h

(use UNUM_SPELLOUT) 	icu::RuleBasedNumberFormat  

Text Transformation

(Transliteration) 	utrans.h 	icu::Transliterator  

Bidirectional Algorithm 	ubidi.h, ubiditransform.h 	C API  

Arabic Shaping 	ushape.h 	C API  

Collation 	ucol.h 	icu::Collator  

String Searching 	usearch.h 	icu::StringSearch  

Index Characters/

Bucketing for Sorted Lists 	(no C API) 	icu::AlphabeticIndex  

Text Boundary Analysis

(Break Iteration) 	ubrk.h 	icu::BreakIterator  

Regular Expressions 	uregex.h 	icu::RegexPattern, icu::RegexMatcher  

StringPrep 	usprep.h 	C API  

International Domain Names in Applications:

 UTS #46 in C/C++, IDNA2003 only via C API 	uidna.h 	idna.h  

Identifier Spoofing & Confusability 	uspoof.h 	C API 

Universal Time Scale 	utmscale.h 	C API  

Layout Engine/Complex Text Layout 	loengine.h 	icu::LayoutEngine,icu::ParagraphLayout  

ICU I/O 	ustdio.h 	ustream.h
```

But the C++ API is not exposed:

> The version of ICU in Windows only exposes the C APIs. It does not expose any of the C++ APIs. Unfortunately, it is impossible to ever expose the C++ APIs due to the lack of a stable ABI in C++.

**References**

- [International Components for Unicode (ICU) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/international-components-for-unicode--icu-)
- [ICU 62.1: Main Page](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/index.html#Module)

Comment: I could swear we both link to ICU dynamically & use its C++ API... is it header - only?